# MVC Google OAuth Login is NULL

Tags: model-view-controller, oauth, google-oauth

Stuck on the MVC OAuth Google login. I tried the Facebook OAuth and it works. I followed the directions from [ASP MVC site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)

I followed the steps as best I could (but I didn't do the Azure setup thing at the beginning). Then created a new project and repeated. Still no go. When I click the Google external login button, I get redirected to the Google site to login. Then I get to the permissions page, I click Accept and then something goes awry because in the Account > ExternalLoginCallBack method, the loginInfo value is NULL ...

In the Google console for developers, I set the REDIRECT URIS to:

```
 https://localhost:44303/signin-google
```

Maybe this is the problem cause I don't know where this (/signin-google) exists in the default MVC project files ...

Anyone have any ideas? It should be straightforward but this part has been frustrating ... am using VS 2013 update 3. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did you enable the Google+ API in the Google Developers Console?  I was having the same problem and I realized I missed that step in the tutorial. Enabling the Google+ API fixed the problem.

Comment: @rycornell A year later, your comment solved the exact same problem for me!